# Parsing javascript into php Object

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following javascript file

sample.js

```
var sampleName = "a nice name";
var sampleObject = {name: 'sample', type: 'text'}
```

I want somehow to parse this file with php and generate the equivalent values, objects into php in order to use them there.

So for example after pasring the js file I would like somehow to be able to access the values with something like that

```
echo $javascriptParser->sampleObject->name; //should return sample
echo $javascriptParser->sampleName; //should return a nice name
```

So far I was not able to find anything like that?
Does anyone know if something like that exists out there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the JS to be valid JSON.

Comment: yeah that would be my last option! I thought about it, this will give me a better and more flexible way to work for both javascript and php together but at that point all files are in javascript. I was just looking for something that would work without having to change all javascript files. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Look for some PHP JavaScript parser.

Comment: export data in jSON Fomat with Js and decode it in php with json_decode function

Comment: Yes I believe something like that should work, but my problem is that this should be done with php alone! so no way for the JS to convert itself into a valid JSON.

Comment: Ok first of all thank you guys for giving nice suggestions on how to tackle this!
I have found a way to accomplish exactly what I wanted and with more effort I will be able to have the result I wanted. The solution for me was [v8js](http://pecl.php.net/package/v8js) After setting it up I was able to work my way following this [link](http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/javascript-in-php-mit-der-v8-engine/) and accomplish what I wanted! At the end of the day I was able to make php have access to the defined javascript variables I hope that this will help Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

pass your string and do some replacements....

```
$json = "{name: 'sample', type: 'text'}";
$search = array(":",", ","{","'");
$replace = array("\":",",\"","{\"","\"");
$json = str_replace($search, $replace, $json);

$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->name;
```

you can write it to a function like:

```
function convert($str)
{
    $search = array(":",", ","{","'");
    $replace = array("\":",",\"","{\"","\"");
    $str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
    $obj = json_decode($str);
    return $obj;
}

$obj = convert("{name: 'sample', type: 'text'}");
echo $obj->name;
```

i guess you should do some about the whitespaces... i just replaced it with it... but better you use something like trim or instead use regexp to replace. so there can be no errors with whitespaces

Comment: Yes I tried that but I have to manipulate the original file to do that. Have in mind that my current structure is like the one posted above and not just the JSON format. ex var objectData = {name:'something'};

Comment: i know, the syntax i used was yours... if it were a json syntax i don't need to replace... you can use fopen to read from file... and than use the function to parse them... so in the end you write your own parser but this shouldn't take more than 30 mins :)
the thing is was you have to do is

open file an read every line

write this to a var or array

walk through the var/array 

use the function to parse your syntax to json and than to object :)